# cambiar comas por punto y coma exportable csv

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Buen día

tengo este query que genera un .csv, pero actualmente me separa las columnas con coma y necesito separarlas por punto y coma. En que parte del código agrego la condición del (;)

```
<?php  
      //export.php  
 if(isset($_POST["export"]))  
 {  
      $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "basededatos");  
      header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');  
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');  
      $output = fopen("php://output", "w");  
      fputcsv($output, array('ID', 'Name', 'Address', 'Gender', 'Designation', 'Age'));  
      $query = "SELECT * from _exportcsv ORDER BY id DESC";  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
      {  
           fputcsv($output, $row);  
      }  
      fclose($output);  
 }  
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes añadir un delimitador a la función fputcsv:

```
fputcsv($output, $row, ';', chr(27));
```

Más información: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: ale ahora en el campo name no se por que razon me esta agregando " al contenido ejemplo: "Juan Perez" y debe aparecer sin doble comilla al inicio y al fin

Comment: @IvanDiazPerez en ese caso tienes que pasarle un cuarto parámetro referente a *enclosure*. Prueba así: `fputcsv($output, $row, ';','');` y si no funciona, prueba así: `fputcsv($output, $row, ';',char(0));`

Comment: vale no me funciona sigue en el campo name el doble comilla "Juan Perez"

Comment: ¿Si usas `char(0)` también, @IvanDiazPerez?

Comment: si al usar char(0) me lanza este error:  <b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function char() in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\export_csv.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br />

Comment: en la linea 15 he copiado: while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
      {  
           fputcsv($output, $row, ';',char(0));
      }

Comment: @IvanDiazPerez, así debería funcionar: **`fputcsv($output, $row, ';', chr(0));`**

Comment: si el campo name contiene espacios en blanco me agrega doble comilla al texto completo al inicio y al final

Comment: ahora me agrega el campo NUL en ambos extremos

Comment: @IvanDiazPerez a mí me funciona bien con `chr(0)`. En la prueba me da resultados así: `14;Antonio Royo Marín
15;Julio Alonso Ampuero
16;Manuel Garrido Bonaño` el segundo campo como ves, tiene espacios y no los encierra entre comillas ni les pone `NULL`

Comment: Podrías probar también con `chr(27)`  en vez de `chr(0)`

Comment: ahora si lo logre muchas gracias con 27 si funciona

Comment: He editado la respuesta con el resultado de este hilo de comentarios